# why does logistic regression still work when # failures is negative?

Tags: r, regression

I am running a binomial glm in R and have some cases where the number of failures is a negative number.  (This occurs because there is some measurement error in the data).  I would expect that the glm function would not work for these cases since log(#successes/#failures) is undefined.  To my surprise, the glm runs and provides estimates of regression coefficients.  I do not understand why glm works nor how to interpret the results.

For example:

```
succ=c(3,0,1,4,2,4,4,7,15,4);
fail=c(1016,1506,1285,1152,868,610,432,211,129,-4);
x_age=c(42.5,47.5,52.5,57.5,62.5,67.5,72.5,77.5,82.5,87.5);

glm(cbind(succ,fail) ~ x_age, family=binomial);

Call:  glm(formula = cbind(succ, fail) ~ x_age, family = binomial)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        x_age  
     -14.15         0.14  

Degrees of Freedom: 8 Total (i.e. Null);  7 Residual
Null Deviance:      105 
Residual Deviance: 17.7         AIC: 47.3
```

Comment: It's significant that the last number in `succ` is 4 because the successes and failures sums to 0. By contrast, this does not work: `> succ=c(3,0,1,4,2,4,4,7,15,1)
> fail=c(1016,1506,1285,1152,868,610,432,211,129,-4); x_age=c(42.5,47.5,52.5,57.5,62.5,67.5,72.5,77.5,82.5,87.5);
> glm(cbind(succ,fail) ~ x_age, family=binomial);
Error in family$linkfun(mustart) : Value -0.75 out of range (0, 1)`

Comment: Nevertheless, the glm fits E[logit(P)] ~ X $\beta$ where logit(P)=log(P/(1-P))=log(#successes/#failures).  So if #failures<0 for a data point log(#successes/#failures) is undefined and I do not see how glm is able to fit the dependent variable logit(P).  That is to say, I do not understand how the condition #successes + #failures = 0 permits glm to work when #failures<0.

Comment: I'm almost certain that it just ignores any row where success+failure < 0. If you drop the last row, you get the same result as your original post.

Comment: I think you are right.  When I remove the last data point entirely, glm produces an identical result.  Thus it does seem that the data point where #successes + #failures = 0 is simply ignored.

Comment: You should feel free to write this up as an answer if you feel confident that this is the case; if not, someone who knows more about `glm` might chime in.

Comment: Crap, I mean successes+failure = 0 in my 2-previous comment.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168637/logistic-regression-what-happens-to-the-coefficients-when-we-switch-the-labels/168641#168641

Comment: @Sycorax A final comment, as discussed elsewhere, logistic glm seems to fit Bernoulli (0,1) outcomes and does not take logits of the actual data.  So the #success and #failures format is a synthetic representation of the underlying Bernoulli outcomes.  Thus the underlying question here is how does R recode a negative number of failures into Bernoulli outcomes?  It seems that when #success + #failure=0 (and #failure<0) the data is simply dropped since it is assumed there are no events; when #success + #failure $\neq$ 0 (and #failure<0)then an ‘out of range’ error is indicated ... as you noted.

Comment: cf. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69820/when-y-1-logit-is-infinity-how-can-you-regress-that-yet-somehow-thats-logi?rq=1

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic.  It is not about R or the implemetation details of glm(), it is about theoretically understanding an surprising result.  Vote to stay open.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen How is this not simply an R source question?

Comment: @Matthew Gunn:  Because it is the underlying statistical question of how this is happening.  This is the question about the estimation algorithm and not about the specific R implementation.

Comment: It isn't clear to me that this is a meaningful statistical question. 'How to properly handle a negative number of failures' is not a sensical statistical question. Instead, it seems to me that the issue is 'how did R's developers decide to handle a situation where users input nonsensical data'. They could also have chosen to return an error, which would have been equally defensible from a statistical point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, I don't think the package authors anticipated a negative number of failures or successes as input. It doesn't make sense, and you shouldn't do it.

#### Going through R source code:

The number of observations for each case are the number of successes + number of failures.

```
n <- y[, 1] + y[, 2]
```

Then y is assigned to be the probability of success:

```
 y <- ifelse(n == 0, 0, y[, 1]/n)
```

Let $s_i$ be the number of successes.
Let $f_i$ be the number of failures.

In the case of $s_i + f_i \neq 0$ we have $ y_i = \frac{s_i}{s_i + f_i}$.

In the case of $s_i + f_i = 0$ we have $y_i = 0$.

OBSERVE WHAT THIS DOES! In your case with 4 successes and -4 failures, the probability of success gets set to zero!

Then it sets mustart:

```
mustart <- (n * y + 0.5)/(n + 1)
```

Let $s_i$ be successes and $f_i$ be count of failures. In summary, we have:

If $s_i + f_i \neq 0$ we have:

$$ \mu^{start}_i = \frac{s_i + .5}{s_i + f_i + 1}$$

While if $s_i + f_i = 0$ we have:
$$ \mu^{start}_i = \frac{1}{2}$$

Then the [c function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/776708efe6003e36f02587ad47b2eaaaa19e2f69/src/library/stats/src/family.c) `logit_link` does a check if mustart is in the range (0,1). So this will throw an error if you passed 4 successes and -2 failures, but it won't throw an error of successes + failures = 0.

```
if (x < 0 || x > 1)
error(_("Value %g out of range (0, 1)"), x);
```

Anyway, I don't see what this has at all to do with statistics. To me, it looks like this R code has some imperfect error checking.